# How can I use Devise with one model and a Wicked-gem wizard with another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, wicked-gem

I am using the Devise gem for `user` login, permitting `:email`and `:password` and the Wicked gem for `profile` completion, permitting `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, and `bio`. User model `has_one :profile` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile` and Profile model `belongs_to :user`. `user_id` for Profile is set as a hidden field in views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb. I will give an explanation of the issue and then list relevant code.

I have gone through Devise and Wicked documentation over and over, but I can't figure out this issue. My controller for Wicked is after_signup_controller. I inserted `binding.pry` into after_signup#show and saw that going through the signup process doesn't hit that controller/action. It seems that after signing up, the Wicked wizard is skipped over. I appended '/after_signup/name' (name is my first step in Wicked) to the localhost URL, with binding.pry in after_signup#show, and saw that Wicked went through all of my steps. This leads me to think that something is overwriting the route to the wizard.

Has anyone tried using Devise and Wicked like this? Please let me know if you can see why the route for Wicked is being overwritten after sign_up.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :profiles
  resources :posts

  devise_for :users, controller: {
    confirmations:  'users/confirmations',
    # omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
    passwords:      'users/passwords',
    registrations:  'users/registrations',
    sessions:       'users/sessions',
    unlocks:        'users/unlocks'
  }

  #Wicked Wizard
  resources :after_signup

  root 'posts#welcome_page'

end
```

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/after_signup'
  end
end

class AfterSignupController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard

  steps :name, :username, :bio, :image

    def show
      binding.pry
      @profile = current_user.profile
      render_wizard(@profile)
    end

    def update
      @profile = current_user.profile
      @profile.update(profile_params)
      render_wizard(@profile)
    end

    private

    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:username, :first_name, :last_name, :bio, :image, :user_id)
    end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  private

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, profile_attributes: [:user_id, :first_name, :last_name, :username, :bio, :image])}
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, profile_attributes: [:user_id, :first_name, :last_name, :username, :bio, :image])}
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
  end
end


##name.html.erb
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@profile, url: wizard_path, method: :put) do |f| %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="field col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_area :first_name, autofocus: true %>
      <%= f.text_area :last_name, autofocus: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Next", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  or <%= link_to "skip", next_wizard_path %>
</div>


##username.html.erb
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@profile, url: wizard_path, method: :put) do |f| %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="field col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_area :username, :placeholder => 'username' autofocus: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Next", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  or <%= link_to "skip", next_wizard_path %>
</div>


##bio.html.erb
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@profile, url: wizard_path, method: :put) do |f| %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="field col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_area :bio, autofocus: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Next", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  or <%= link_to "skip", next_wizard_path %>
</div>


##image.html.erb
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@profile, url: wizard_path, method: :put) do |f| %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="field col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_field :image, autofocus: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
</div>
```

This is my first time posting a question to Stack Overflow. In addition to addressing this issue, please let me know if I've listed too many files.

Comment: For your after sign up redirect, can you use an url_helper instead? Strings can be prone to error.

Comment: Also, how badly do you want to use the wicked-gem? Typically, people Implement a lot of profile functionality on the user model. Especially if it's a one to one relationship. If a user can have many profiles, then wicked might make more sense, IMO.

Comment: Just looked up the documentation. (Link to that for future questions), wicked is a state machine helping gem. I'll have to look at this in depth on a computer (on phone ATM)

Comment: By URL helper do you mean redirect_to or the path name, after_signup_path? The Wicked gem is a requirement but it is not a requirement to use Profile. In all examples I've seen, when linking Devise with Wicked, the model from Devise is transferred to Wicked and updated. I'm curious if that is the only way it can be used.

Comment: @DannyBeyrer i also have same probelm .. i want to redirect to customer after sign in path.. but its not working. do you have any idea.. how to again redirect to create method in builds controller. when user sign in